# Java SpringBoot Rest OAuth2 Principal is null

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I tried different tutorials on **Java SpringBoot REST OAuth2**  authentication. I tried to and combine them with simple web form authentication, but still i am not able to get Principal class object. I got `null` every time on my Rest Controller (showed in lines bellow), am I missing something?

**AuthorizationServerConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String REALM = "MY_OAUTH_REALM";

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120).//Access token is only valid for 2 minutes.
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);//Refresh token is only valid for 10 minutes.
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore).authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

}
```

**ResourceServerConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "rest_api";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}
```

**OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .anonymous().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

}
```

**UserServiceImpl.java**

```
import cz.uhk.ppro.semestralniprojekt.model.user.User;
import cz.uhk.ppro.semestralniprojekt.model.user.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

@Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = findByUsername(s);
        if(user == null){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getAuthority());
    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    private List getAuthority() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }

}
```

**ApiController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping("/monthFinanceOverview")
    public MonthFinanceOverview monthFinanceOverview(
            @RequestParam(value = "month", required = false) String month,
            Principal principal
    ) {
        DateTimeFormatter monthDateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        User user = users.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        //Here i got error every time
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>cz.uhk.ppro</groupId>
    <artifactId>semestralni-projekt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>semestralni-projekt</name>
    <description>Semestrální projekt Java EE, Spring</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: Which version of springboot are you using?

Comment: If using springboot > 1.5 , add `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3` to your application.properties and let me know the result.

Comment: It worked, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `@EnableResourceServer` to your controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@EnableResourceServer
public class ApiController { ... }
```

**EDIT :**

If using springboot > 1.5 , add `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order=3` to your application.properties.

Comment: Unfortunately nope :-(

Comment: I have edited the answer with the solution that worked.

Comment: And what if I want to use one application as REST API service and webservice. Can I use OAuth2 and form authentication in one app?

Comment: Yes. It would be possible. But you will have to search for the relevant tutorial online.